# Почему все время undefined(когда запрос без параметров и без поиска геолокации(lat и lng),оно работает)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export const fetchIataViaGeo = createAsyncThunk(
  'iata/fetchIataViaGeo',

  async () => {
    const error = () => {
      alert('Sorry, we could not find your location. Please enter manually.');
    };
    const succuess = async (position) => {
      const lat = position.coords.latitude;
      const lng = position.coords.longitude;
      const res = await axios.get(
        `https://airlabs.co/api/v9/nearby?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}&distance=45&api_key=...`
      );
      console.log(res.data.response.airports);
      return await res.data.response.airports;
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(succuess, error);
  }
);
```

так работает

```
export const fetchIataViaGeo = createAsyncThunk(
  'iata/fetchIataViaGeo',

  async () => {
     
      const res = await axios.get(
        `https://airlabs.co/api/v9/nearby?lat=55.22&lng=22.23&distance=45&api_key=...`
      );
      console.log(res.data.response.airports);
      return await res.data.response.airports;
    };
    
  }
);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: в первом случае ничего не возвращается из функции переданной в createAsyncThunk - как результат получается `undefined` - во втором случае - возвращается, поэтому и работает